# Background picture in turtle.TurtleScreen() does not show correctly in tkinter

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

**Code 1:** Creates a `Tk()` window, a `Frame()`, `Canvas()` to host a `turtle.TurtleScreen()` with a certain background picture. The dimensions of these widgets are not defined at the outset. Instead, they are defined after widget creation using the tkinter's `.configure()` method and turtle's `.screensize()` method. **The issue here is that the background picture does not appear correctly even though the turtle screensize appears correct.**

**Code 2:** It does the same job as Code 1 except that it first obtains the size of the image and uses it to define the size of the `Canvas` widget first before displaying it as the background image of `turtle.TurtleScreen()`. The background image does appear correctly.

**Questions:**

1. Why does the issue occur in code 1 and how to overcome the issue, i.e. correctly show a background image in `turtle.TurtleScreen()` in the event of a change in background image size?
2. Why is the sizes of `Frame` and `Canvas` widgets 2 pixel larger for code 1 than for code 2, even though the `Canvas` is defined with `borderwidth=0`? Is this something to do with the Canvas's default borderwidth=2?

**Code 1:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle as tt


root = tk.Tk()

def getsize( widget ):
    widget.update_idletasks()
    w = widget.winfo_width()
    h = widget.winfo_height()
    print( 'w={}, h={}\n'.format(w,h) )
    return w,h

app = tk.Frame( root,  )
canvas = tk.Canvas( app, bg='yellow', borderwidth=0, )
app.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' ) 
canvas.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' )
print('\nFrame'); aw, ah = getsize( app )
print('canvas'); cw, ch = getsize( canvas )

pic = 'test.gif'
screen = tt.TurtleScreen( canvas )
screen.bgpic( pic )
screen.bgcolor( 'pink' )
screen.update()
print( 'Turtle :' )
print( 'screen size = ', screen.screensize() )
print( 'screen attributes = ', screen.__dict__ )
print( 'screen.bgpic() = ', screen.bgpic() )
photoimage = screen._bgpics[pic]
pw = photoimage.width()
ph = photoimage.height()
print( '\nphotoimage width={} height={}'.format( pw, ph) )

canvas.configure( width=pw+2, height=ph+2 )
screen.screensize( pw+2, ph+2 )
screen.bgpic( pic )

print('\nFrame'); aw, ah = getsize( app )
print('canvas'); cw, ch = getsize( canvas )
```

**Code 2:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle as tt


root = tk.Tk()

pic ='test.gif'
image = tk.PhotoImage( file=pic )
iw = image.width()
ih = image.height()
print( 'image width={} height={}\n'.format( iw, ih) )

def getsize( widget ):
    widget.update_idletasks()
    w = widget.winfo_width()
    h = widget.winfo_height()
    print( 'w={}, h={}\n'.format(w,h) )
    return w,h

app = tk.Frame( root, )
canvas = tk.Canvas( app, width=iw, height=ih, bg='yellow', borderwidth=0 )
app.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' ) 
canvas.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' )
print('Frame'); aw, ah = getsize( app )
print('canvas'); cw, ch = getsize( canvas )

screen = tt.TurtleScreen( canvas )
screen.bgpic( pic )
screen.bgcolor( 'pink' )
screen.update()
print( 'Turtle :' )
print( 'screen size = ', screen.screensize() )
print( 'screen attributes = ', screen.__dict__ )
print( 'screen.bgpic() = ', screen.bgpic() )
photoimage = screen._bgpics[pic]
pw = photoimage.width()
ph = photoimage.height()
print( '\nphotoimage width={} height={}'.format( pw, ph) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to Q1:**

After further research, I discovered `TurtleScreen()` has an attribute called `.cv` to point to the `tk.Canvas` widget that is passed into it. As with all `tk.Canvas` widget, there is a need to update(i.e. configure) its `scrollregion` to show the new visible area of the `tk.Canvas` when there is a change. The "scrollregion" option states how large an area the canvas can be scrolled.

So the changes to Code 1, I needed to replace:

```
canvas.configure( width=pw+2, height=ph+2 )
screen.screensize( pw+2, ph+2 )
screen.bgpic( pic )
```

with

```
canvas.configure( width=pw, height=ph, borderwidth=0 )
w = int(screen.cv.cget("width"))
h = int(screen.cv.cget("height"))
screen.cv.configure(scrollregion = (-w//2, -h//2, w//2+1, h//2 ))
print( '\nscreen.cv width={} height={}'.format( w, h) )
```

**Answer to Q2:**

The difference in the report Frame and Canvas sizes by 2 pixel was due to the +2 in used in Code 1:

```
canvas.configure( width=pw+2, height=ph+2 )
```

Instead, I should have used:

```
canvas.configure( width=pw, height=ph )
```

It seems that a Canvas does consume 1 row/column of pixel to form it's boundary.